# How to instantiate an imageview by using if else condition?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

In my project, I am parsing an XML file. I have used if else condition to print the value in the Log cat. But, I need to know how to instantiate an ImageView by using if else condition. Here is the sample code which I am using.

For example,

```
if (parentTag.equals("Owners")) {

    **it must instantiate an ImageView**

                        }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

XML:

```
<Contents>
    <Owners>
        <Owner>
            <Name>Joselito Dimaculangan</Name>
            <Age>16</Age>
            <EmailAddress>joselito123@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
        </Owner>
        <Owner>
            <Name>Noemi De Galileo</Name>
            <Age>14</Age>
            <EmailAddress>noemi111@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
        </Owner>
    </Owners>
    <Dogs>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Barky</Name>
            <Birthday>June 29, 2012</Birthday>
        </Dog>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Jumbo</Name>
            <Birthday>December 30, 2012</Birthday>
        </Dog>
    </Dogs>
</Contents>
```

Main Activity:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {

                    dataItem = (ParsedDataSet) i.next();

                    /*
                     * parentTag can also represent the main type of data, in
                     * our example, "Owners" and "Dogs"
                     */
                    String parentTag = dataItem.getParentTag();

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "parentTag: " + parentTag);

                    if (parentTag.equals("Owners")) {


                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Name: " + dataItem.getName());
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Age: " + dataItem.getAge());
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                                "EmailAddress: " + dataItem.getEmailAddress());

                    }

                    else if (parentTag.equals("Dogs")) {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Name: " + dataItem.getName());
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Birthday: " + dataItem.getBirthday());
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

Create the image view in the layout itself, but set it's visibility to 'invisible' or 'gone' depending on how your layout params work.

Then in your condition set the visibility to View.VISIBLE.

Layout

```
...
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
...
```

Activity

```
ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
if (parentTag.equals("Owners")) {
    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

or

If you'd like to programatically create the view:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);        
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.myImage));
yourParentView.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I will try and let you know